# Iterate over items of a specific interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have an array of object that implement the `IItem` interface:

```
interface IItem {
  getId() : string;
}

interface ISortableItem extends IItem {
  getSortIndex() : number;
}

var items : IItem[] = [ ... ];
```

Now I want to obtain only the items that implement the `ISortableItem` interface, but I don't think this information is available at runtime anymore. I could use something like this:

```
for (var i of items) {
  if ((<ISortableItem>i).getSortIndex) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Although it works, my programmer's heart starts bleeding ;-) Is there a more elegant way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a class in your situation.

```
class Item {
   getId() { .. }
}

class SortableItem extends Item {
   getSortIndex() { ... }
}

...

items.filter( item => item instanceof SortableItem )
```

By doing this you will allow the detection on runtime and compile time.

Comment: I cannot use a class, because each class implements the `getId` different. It's also possible to add the `getSortIndex` as an optional method in the `IItem` interface. Somehow, separating the interfaces looks much cleaner.

Comment: Well, this question and my answer is opinionated anyway, but keep in mind that you can build your classes by implementing the interface ( `class Item implements IItem` ). IMHO the most important thing by using TypeScript is interface and class organization. So sometimes code patterns from JS will not be appropriate to use with TypeScript.